# Python 2.7 . Is there any function that does the same than u'string' with accented strings?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

Here is my problem: I need a way or function that makes the same than u'string'. For example:

```
> s1=u'Estás'
> s1
>>u'Est\xe1s'

> s2='Estás'
> s2
>>'Est\xa0s'
```

An then i try to convert it to unicode

```
>s2=unicode(s2,'latin-1')
>s2
>>u'Est\xa0s'
```

You can see that the escape characters are different and if i print both

```
>print s1,s2
>>Estás Est s
```

In my python script i get the strings from some files and i know they can contain accents so i need a way to convert them to unicode with the proper escape character. Any ideas? Thx in advance.

PD: I know that python 3 have some solutions for that but it's compulsory for me to work with 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unicode code point for `á` is 0xe1. The string you've entered as `s2` is encoded in cp850, where `á` has the byte representation 0xa0, and not latin-1. So you have to use the correct encoding.

Comment: Thank's. Didn't know the correct encoding. Is this encoding the same for all the accents (I mean ´ ,`,¨ and ^)?

Comment: The encoding depends on the terminal, you've entered the text, or the program, that have written an explicit file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the solution =)

Comment: @Penneke, you're probably on Windows.  The comand `chcp` at the command prompt will show the console encoding.  It's not necessarily `cp850`.  `cp437` gives the same encoding for that character.  In Python `import sys; sys.stdout.encoding` will also tell you the console encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in thinking that your bytestring is encoded in latin-1. There doesn't seem to be any good reason to think this; much more likely it is in utf-8.

Also note it's much clearer to use `x.decode(encoding)` rather than `unicode(x, encoding)` to decode to Unicode.

```
>>> s2.decode('utf-8')
u'Est\xe1s'
```

Comment: The problem is that trying to use decode with utf-8 i get a traceback saying that the byte in position 3 can't be decoded. I think you're using decode after using unicode or maybeyou declared s2=u'Estás'

Comment: >>> s2='Estás'
>>> s2.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 3: invalid s
tart byte

Comment: As the other Daniel says, looks like your terminal's encoding is cp850. So `s2.decode('cp850')` should work fine.